# How to use managed_file to upload many files

Tags: forms, files

I'm looking for a way to upload many files by means of the [`managed_file`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) form API element. I would like it be like while uploading for node where is 'add new item' button.
How to do it?

Comment: What is managed_file field. Is it a field you created.

Comment: It's #type from Drupal Form API. I want to do it by code.

Comment: If it's about Form API, it's not a "field", it's a "form element" - these terms have very specific meaning. So, if I read you right, you should remove tag [tag:fields] and add [tag:form-api]. And of course edit content to replace word "field".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [plupload form element](http://drupal.org/node/1647890) instead. Install [Plupload integration module](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) and then use something like:

```
$form['my_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'plupload',
  '#title' => t('Upload files'),
  '#description' => t('This multi-upload widget uses Plupload library.'),
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt  ods odp'),
    'my_custom_file_validator' => array('some validation criteria'),
  ),
  '#plupload_settings' => array(
    'runtimes' => 'html5',
    'chunk_size' => '1mb',
  ),
);
```

Comment: I installed it and there is only info like "This multi-upload widget uses Plupload library.
Allowed file types: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp."

Comment: Check with Firebug, probably there is some javascript error.

Comment: Paths issue, however I would like to use the managed_file type.

Comment: @daroPL Sadly, there is no "managed_files" type, just "managed_file".

Comment: I had a look on `file_field_widget_form()` and there it is done it by `manage_file`.

Answer (score 0):

I used below Solution. Its worked for me.
[Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/add-more-button-for-text-field-file-field-using-ahah-with-drupal-7-form)